# Change MariaDB password with entrypoint.sh in docker-container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mariadb

I have lines inside a entrypoint-script that should change the password for root@localhost / root@%:

```
service mariadb start
# set db root password
mysql --user='root' --password='root' -e "\
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; \
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

it doesn't matter how to format the mysql-command: --passwordroot -proot -p"root" ect.

it always throws an error and won't change the password:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

how can i get my entrypoint-script to change the password?

Here is the part of my Dockerfile which is not outcommented for debugging:

```
    FROM ubuntu:22.10
    
    ENV DB_ROOT_PW=root
    
    COPY src/* /tmp/
    
    
    RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y \
        cron
    
    # db, webserver
    RUN apt-get install -y \
        mariadb-server \
        mysqltuner \
        apache2

    RUN service mariadb start && \
        mysql -h localhost -u root -e "\
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; \
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
    
    RUN cp /tmp/docker_entry.sh /usr/local/bin/
    RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker_entry.sh
    ENTRYPOINT [ "docker_entry.sh" ]
```

Doesn't matter if i set the pw to "root" in the dockerfile or not.
However the command works if i jump into the image and run it by hand.

### **Update:**

I removed everything from the entrypoint-script except

```
service mariadb start
```

and it throws

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

If i leave the root pw empty (not set during build in dockerfile). There is no error thrown. After setting it manually in the container the error occurs every time the container restarts.

Is this something i can get rid of as this error is confusing and wrong?

Comment: please share your dockerfile

Comment: Commands like `service` largely don't work in Docker for various reasons.  The standard [Docker Hub `mariadb` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) can set the root password via an environment variable; can you use that image instead of building your own?  Are you sure the database password is `root` when this command runs (the command itself changes the password to `test`)?

Comment: thank you @DavidMaze but for my project i need to use ubuntu22.10. this is just a short snippet as the container has a size of 10gb at the end. containing a web-project with frontend, db... working with python etc.pp. my project is already working on source and i want to convert it into docker

Comment: Are you trying to run it as a virtual machine with multiple services embedded, or as a set of connected single-process containers?

Comment: @DavidMaze like a VM. its already working. and i was able to cut it down. i will update my question. i removed all lines. just only ,,service mariadb start" and this seems to throw the error. i dont know why. no error if i leave the root pw unset